# Make a user profile accessible to current user ONLY

Tags: django

So I wanna make a page where the user can see some details of them. No one else can see this page.

The url would be

```
path('accounts/perfil/<int:pk>', views.Perfil.as_view()),
```

So I need to check if the logged in user is the same as in the url. How can I do this with a class based view?

Comment: Do you have a `Perfil` model? If so, please show it. Please show anything you've written for your `Perfil` view so far.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass id in the url. You can access the logged in user from request.user 
and can check using is_authenticated() or not.

```
path('accounts/profile/', views.Profile.as_view()),

class Profile(TemplateView):
  def get(self, request, *args, **Kwargs):
      if request.user.is_authenticated():
        ## send details
      else:
        return other
```

for rest api

```
class Profile(APIView):
   permission_classes = (permission.IsAuthenticated,)
   def get(self, request,*args, **kwargs):
      return response.Response(UserSerailizer(request.user).data)
```

if you want to add the id in url

```
class Profile(Temaplet):
  def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
     user = User.objects.get(id=kwars['id'])
     if user.is_authenticated():
        ## do action
```

Comment: This will render the content if the user is authenticated, but it means a user can see *other* profiles as well.

Comment: nope, how can other user see other profile, i am feteching the user from request

Comment: I have a profile with id `1`, I fetch `/accounts/prefil/2` (so another user), the test checks `request.user.is_authenticated()` so checks if I have logged in, I have, so it renders the details of a profile with id 2.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem my url is accounts/profile/ it is not including any id

Comment: but that is aganst the question where the url is: `path('accounts/perfil/<int:pk>', views.Perfil.as_view())`. Frequently for example admins *can* see the profile.

Comment: I have written that, you don't need to pass the user id, in that case

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem So I wanna make a page where the user can see some details of them. No one else can see this page. question first line

Comment: yes and most software manuals say one needs to make software where *nobody else* can easily change in *somebody else* (easy to change) :) Not doing that is eventually why a lot of software companies eventually take a long time to make "straightforward" changes, because the "workload" to make changes, eventually scales quadratic.

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution would be to remove the `id` from the url and just render data from the currently logged-in user in the template; maybe something like this:

**urls.py**

```
from . import views
path('accounts/perfil/', views.PerfilView.as_view(), name='perfil'),
```

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class PerfilView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'perfil.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx['more_user_data'] = self.request.user.something()
        return ctx
```

**perfil.html**

```
<p>
    Hello, {{ user.first_name }}
    <small>{{ more_user_data }}</small>
</p>
```

Note that in the view there is `self.request.user` and in the template there is the [template variable `user`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#users) that holds the current user.